# implement sound in Qt Creator

Tags: qt

I start to work with Qt Creator and I would develop a base program that when I push a button, a song start.
I have already managed the button.
May you recommend me the main command that I could use when I include QSound?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a music you can:

- Create a `_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);`
- Get the file to read `QUrl file = QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Music"), "", tr("")));`
- Set the file to read in the media player `_player->setMedia(file);`
- Set the default volume `_player->setVolume(50);`
- Start the music `_player->play();`

In your case, the only thing you should change is to don't start the music directly and write a slot for your button. When you are in the slot, call `_player->play();`